# Protecting Unity3d .apk file (Oculus)

Tags: unity-game-engine, proguard, obfuscation, oculus

I'm looking for ways to protect the .apk file before publishing it on *SideQuest* market. I know that is technically not possible to achieve a 100% level of protection, but I would be happy in making things a bit harder for people trying to snoop into the source code after a succesful de-compilation.

I'm currently using **IL2CPP** as Backend Script system which AFAIK could help, but I was also looking into **ProGuard**. Unfortunately, if I try to activate the minification (`Build Settings --> Player Settings --> Other Options --> Publishing Settings --> Minification --> ProGuard`)  the app stops working on my Oculus Quest.

Is there any way to make it work or any other means to achieve a higher level of protection?

Comment: I personally haven't tried that but give it a try: [obfuscator](https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/Obfuscapk)

Comment: You can at most obfuscate it or include some red herring code to put them off... Besides that there is nothing you can do against someone really determined to decompile your code and snoop around in it. `"Is there any way to make it work"` We'll need more info than that (logs, versions etc) to even be able to help you with that ;)